# how to pass whole data using ajax in php using keypress event

Tags: php, ajax

I am passing empcode using key press event, but my whole empcode is not transfered and the last digit is cut.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#e_code").keypress(function(){
             //var dataString=document.getElementById("e_code").value;
            var dataString = 'e_code='+ $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "getdata.php",
             data: dataString,
             cache: false,
             success: function (html) {
            $('#details').html(html);
            $('#custTrnHistory').show()
          }
       });
    });   
  });

  on getdata file code is
```

Answer (score 0):

write code in `keyup` instead of `keypress`

```
$("#e_code").keyup(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your keypress on document --- try this

```
 $(document).on('keypress',"#e_code",function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var minlength = 5; //change as per the the length of empcode
$("#e_code").keyup(function () {
var inputvalue= $(this).val();
if (inputvalue.length >= minlength ) {
var dataString = 'e_code='+ $(this).val();

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
 url: "getdata.php",
data: dataString,
   cache: false,
 success: function (html) {
$('#details').html(html);
$('#custTrnHistory').show()
  }
 });
}
});
});
```